# How to change strings when changing Build Variant

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have three `productFlavors`:
 `development`
 `production`
 `staging`

```
productFlavors {

    development {
        applicationId "com.fakenameapp.app.development"
    }

    production {
        applicationId "com.fakenameapp.app.production"
    }

    staging {
        applicationId "com.fakenameapp.app.staging"
    }

}
```

Each have a directory in `/src`, with copied values directory from `/main`

the `string.xml` have different string values

But when selecting the build variant and compiling. The strings values stays the same from main. Am I missing something ? as this is the first time I set it up

[image]

Comment: Do you have "src/main/res/values/string.xml", "src/development/res/values/string.xml", "src/production/res/values/string.xml" and "src/staging/res/values/string.xml"? Could you please share more detail about your folder structure?

Comment: Yes I do. I have everything that is in main/values/. And all I changed was strings.xml

Comment: Please edit your question to include either a diagram or an image of your directory structure of your flavors/project. The more details the better.

Comment: Sorry I definitely should have @Dr.Nitpick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure your directory structure is created properly. Expected as per your question would be as follows:

```
src
--main 
-----res
-------values
----------string.xml
--production
-----res
-------values
----------string.xml
--development
-----res
-------values
----------string.xml
--staging
-----res
-------values
----------string.xml
```

Comment: Great. I did not have res in there